# css transition from top 100% to bottom 0

Tags: html, css

So from this question [Transition effects Top vs. Bottom in CSS is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21732263/6554121) I can't do top to bottom transition, so how would I go about trying to get an effect like this (but with transition)

```js
function show_box()
{
    let box = document.getElementById("box")
    box.className += " show";
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  top: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
  position: fixed;
}

.box.show {
  top: initial;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="box">
  sdome box with some large text
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  sdfasdfsdf
</div>
<button onclick="show_box()">Show</button>
```

Comment: hi, add transition in this class .box.show

Answer (score 1):

```js
function show_box()
{
    let box = document.getElementById("box")
    box.className += " show";
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  position: fixed;
}

.box.show {
  top: initial;
  bottom: 0;
  height:200px;
  -webkit-transition:height 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="box">

</div>
<button onclick="show_box()">Show</button>
```

Comment: The top/bottom isn't actually required, but the height helped.

Comment: Although I think something that can auto adjust to the height rather than hardcoding it would be more optimal.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function showBox(boxId)
{
    let box = document.getElementById(boxId)
    box.className += " show";
}
```

```css
.box {
  background: #cdf; 
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box#box-2 {
  left: 220px;
}
.box#box-3 {
  left: 430px;
}

.box > .inner {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box.show > .inner {
  top: 0;
  transition: top 2s ease;
}

.box > .inner > .subInner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: flex-end;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box-1">
  <button onClick="showBox('box-1')">Show</button>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="subInner">
      <p>Some content in box-1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="box" id="box-2">
  <button onClick="showBox('box-2')">Show</button>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="subInner">
      <p>Content of box-2 with different height</p>
      <p>Content of box-2</p>
      <p>Content of box-2 again</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box" id="box-3">
  <button onClick="showBox('box-3')">Show</button>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="subInner">
      <p>Third box content</p>
      <p>Third box content again</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've added fiddle here as snippet.

**UPDATE**
I changed boxes behavior from css hover to js-button click event and I'm afraid I've no ideas anymore, because fixed position of boxes made rather strict restrictions to possible solutions, which depends on specific conditions of your task.

Comment: not quite what I wanted, I wanted it to come from the bottom up, so sliding up basically

Comment: @A.Lau I've update fiddle to slide from bottom to top.

Comment: I need it to only go partially, optimally only as big as the content. I've updated my snippet, you should probably use that as your basis. Also position fixed.

Comment: @A.Lau What about new snippet variant with wrapper and dynamic content?

Comment: it's getting close, but since I want to use it via the window, I don't really want to have a 100% wide/high box that would prevent me from clicking other things.

Comment: @A.Lau I've update answer again, and I'm afraid that's all I can help you with you question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153842/discussion-between-cnnr-and-a-lau).